# how to check if the variable content is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the content of variable is changed then execute the line of code else skip, how can i check that

```
$("#weektime").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).selectedDays();
    $("#weektime1").css("display", "flex");
if(previous value of x != current value of x){
        foo(x[0]);
}
});
```

Comment: You need two variables - one that holds the previous value, one that holds the new value. Alternatively, one that holds the current value and one that is a boolean that is set to `true` when there is a change and you reset it to false in your check.

Comment: where will you define the second variable, inside the click event or globally.

Comment: Wherever you're getting the first variable from. They should be next to each other. Of course, in order to make sure both are always set, you probably want something like a setter, so you do `setX(42)` and it sets `x` and `oldX`. You could also go with [setter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

Answer (score 0):

Include another variable to hold the original/previous value of the actual variable. Check if the value of the previous/original variable is equal to the actual variable value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var previous;
 $("#weektime").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).selectedDays();
    $("#weektime1").css("display", "flex");
    if(previous !== x){
        foo(x[0]);
    }
    previous = x;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> If the content of variable is changed

in your code, the variable `x` (currentValue) is retrieved each time

```
var x = $(this).selectedDays();
```

so it's not a case of the "variable changed" as it's always new each click event, but rather the value it comes from

```
$(this).selectedDays();
```

As you're getting your `x` value from a DOM element, I suggest storing the "original" value against the element as well, then your code can be applied to any number of elements without having to create a new variable each time.

```
$(this).data("oldValue");
```

Updating your code:

```
$("#weektime").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var oldValue = $(this).data("previous-selected-days") || 0;
    var currentValue = $(this).selectedDays();
   

    if (oldValue != currentValue) {
        foo(currentValue[0]);

        // optionally update the "oldvalue"
        $(this).data("previous-selected-days", currentValue);
    }
});
```

If you have an "original" value rather than "previous value" then set this either in the DOM

```
<input data-previous-selected-days="123">
```

or at startup

```
$(function() { 
    // after initialising the control
    $("#weektime").data("previous-selected-days", $("#weektime").selectedDays());
});
```